# composer laravel create project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to use laravel, when I start a project and type `composer create-project /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test_laravel` in terminal it shows

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
Could not find package /applications/mamp/htdocs/test_laravel with stabilit  
y stable.
```

and

```
create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

How to fix it ?
and is this step equal to create folder and file like I download from laravel git `laravel-master.zip` ?

--
MAMP php5.4.10

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You are missing a parameter in the command. It should be in this order:

```
composer create-project [PACKAGE] [DESTINATION PATH] [--FLAGS]
```

You're mistakingly specifying your local path as the Composer/Packagist package you wish to create a project from. Hence the "Could not find package" message.

Simply make sure you're specifying the Laravel package and you should be good to go:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test_laravel
```

Comment: Why not just `composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp`, do this command in that folder where you want the project to be installed.

Answer (score 15):

I also had same problem then I found [this](http://laravel.com/docs/quick) on there documentation page

So if you want to create a project by name of `test_laravel` in directory `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` then what you need to do is

go to your project parent directory

> cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

and fire this command

> composer create-project laravel/laravel test_laravel
>   --prefer-dist

that's it, this is really easy and it also creates Application Key automatically for you

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel test_laravel --prefer-dist worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two simple methods for creating laravel Project

**Method 1**

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <project-name>
```

**Method 2**

```
laravel new <project-name>
```

Method 2 might require you to run one extra command

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

if you face 'laravel command not found' error

Answer (score 3):

My few cents. The forward-slash in the package name (laravel**/**laravel) is matter. If you put back-slash you will get package not found stability error.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your composer is up to date. write in the cmd

```
composer create-project –-prefer-dist laravel/laravel NameOfProject "Version"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create project
2. Open: Root (htdocs)\
3. Press: Shift + Open command windows here
4. Type: `php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist
   laravel/laravel lar-project "5.7.*"`

Answer (score 1):

Following command will help you to create a new project with a specific version on laravel

`composer create-project laravel/laravel:8.* project_name`

supported versions are below

```
laravel/laravel:8.*
laravel/laravel:7.*
laravel/laravel:6.*
laravel/laravel:5.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont write `with stability stable` in the command ,

in your composer.json file, put 
`"minimum-stability": "stable"`  before the closing curly bracket.

Comment: Thanks for reply! where can i find composer.json file?

Comment: did you mean the correct step: I still have to download larval-master.zip and unzip, copy the file/folder inside to myproject(test_laravel). then type command in terminal `composer create-project /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test_laravel`

Comment: .. so I type the command `composer create-project /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test_laravel` in terminal but where is composer.json file?

Answer (score 0):

you first need to install laravel using  command: `composer global require laravel/installer` then use `composer create-project` command your problem will be solved.
I hope your problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to locate the project directory in cmd
After this fire below command and 'first_laravel_app' is the project name you can replace it with your own project name.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel first_laravel_app --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run Laravel Project in Windows**

**Install XAMPP**
-----
**Install Composer**
*Command Line Installation*

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

php composer-setup.php

php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

```
   -----
```

**Install Laravel**

composer global require "laravel/installer"

```
   -----
```

**Create Laravel Project**

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel MyFirstLaravelProject
.

Answer (score -1):

No this step isn't equal to downloading the laravel.zip
by using the command
**composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel** 
you actually download the laravel project as well as dependent packages so its one step ahead.

If you are using windows environment you can solve the problem by **deleting the composer environment variable** you created to install the composer. And this command will run properly.